# More efficient Ruby way to map attribute in array of objects to another array?

Tags: ruby

I won't repeat my question here, but is there are more efficient way to write this?

```
  def recruits_names
    names = []
    for r in self.referrals do
      names << r.display_name
    end

    return names
  end
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001491) method:

> Returns a new array with the results of running block once for every element in enum.

```
def recruits_names
  self.referrals.map { |r| r.display_name }
end
```

[Update] As indicated by Staelen in the comments, this example can be shortened even further to:

```
def recruits_names
  self.referrals.map(&:display_name)
end
```

For the curious, this is because `&` calls `to_proc` on the object following it (when used in a method call), and `Symbol` implements `to_proc` to return a `Proc` that executes the method indicated by the symbol on each value yielded to the block (see [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Symbol.html#M000780)).

Comment: Ruby is so intuitive that the answer is actually already contained in the question :-) "More efficient Ruby way to **map** attribute [...]" Don't you just love that?

Comment: What if you wanted to return more than one attribute, but not all?