# How do I add each price to the current price?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am trying to write a method that will find each price and add it to the current price.

Quote.rb:

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  def calc_price
    sum = 0
    items.each do |item|
      item.price
    end
    sum = (item1 + item2 etc)
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not important whether you're new to Ruby or a veteran. We care about good questions, and whether you try to figure them out before you ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice feature about the more current Rubies:

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5]
values.inject(:+) # => 15
```

Now, that said, you're working with a database, so have it [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) the records. From the documentation:

> Calculates the sum of values on a given column. The value is returned with the same data type of the column, 0 if there’s no row. See calculate for examples with options.

```
Person.sum('age') # => 4562
```

Comment: Just curious, if I pre-load all quotes with `.includes(:items)` option, will the summing on database still happen at the database's end? I am thinking on the lines of `Quote.includes(:items).find(:all)`

Comment: I have asked a detailed question for my concerns here http://stackoverflow.com/q/19462427/1860929 
In general(no relation to OP), will it be a recommended practise to use these methods directly?

Answer (score 2):

```
items.inject(0){|sum, item| sum += item.price}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can offload the calculation to the database.

```
def total_price
  items.sum('price')
end
```

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum

Comment: Just curious, if I pre-load all quotes with `.includes(:items)` option, will the summing on database still happen at the database's end? I am thinking on the lines of `Quote.includes(:items).find(:all)`.

Comment: The calculation only happens at the database's end if you use the `sum` method, which takes a model attribute as argument. So I don't see why that would be any different with eager loading.

Comment: Eager loading will load associated `items` objects into memory at the same time as the original `Quote` objects. My confusion is, if the objects are already loaded into the memory, will using `sum` make another query to the database to sum it on the database's end, or will it use the in memory objects, in which case, the calculation is not being offloaded to the database?

Comment: That's a good question, you should open a new question in SO for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum the price within the `.each` loop

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  def calc_price
    sum = 0
    items.each do |item|
      sum += item.price
    end
  end
end
```

You can further compact that loop to a single line using

```
items.each {|item| sum += item.price}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
items.map(&:price).inject(0, :+)
```

The map part maps the items array to an array of prices and the inject part starts with 0 and adds each element of the price array.

[Mapping StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216275/more-efficient-ruby-way-to-map-attribute-in-array-of-objects-to-another-array)

[inject docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

[inject examples](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html)