# Do ActiveRecord::Calculations with eager loading make multiple database queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

My confusion stems from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19462024/1860929), where OP has a model like

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  def calc_price
    sum = 0
    #logic for summation
  end
end
```

In the answers, a couple of people have suggested using the sum method directly for calculating the sum of attributes

```
def total_price
  items.sum('price')
end
```

If I eager load data using `Quote.includes(:items).find(:all)`, does the sum happen at the database's end, or does it use the objects already loaded in memory? If it uses the objects already loaded in memory, then the calculations are not being offloaded to the database.

Will it make the database query twice, once to preload, next to sum up the prices?

Extending the same logic to all [ActiveRecord::Calculations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html), Will I hit my database everytime if I do a `count` or `average` or other such methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Calculations` (which includes `sum`, `count`, `average`) will hit the database even if the items are eager-loaded. For e.g.

```
 quotes = Quote.includes(:items).find(:all)
 # two queries one to fetch quotes and one to fetch all associated items

 items = quotes.first.items
 # no query as items are eager loaded

 total_price = quotes.first.items.sum(:price)
 # one query to get sum of item prices for the first quote
 # summation is done by the database
```

To check this, run the rails console and log to the console using `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`. You can then see what db queries are being made for each method.

Comment: The important thing isn't if it hits the database just to sum, it's that the one hit will return a single value. It's extremely fast compared to anything else you could do, and probably faster than iterating over the data in memory.

Comment: I just ran a benchmark to compare `records.sum(:attr)` and `records.to_a.sum(&:attr)` where `records` were eagerloaded in both cases and `records.to_a.sum(&:attr)` is about 16 times faster than hitting the DB.

Of course each use case is different but I thought I'd provide a data point.